# Nested json filtering using jq or cel

Tags: jq, common-expression-language

Need to return payload.* json path where condition payload.*.*.cities.name = city_x matches. Tried looking google cel or jq for this case. did not find way for this so far.

Case 1 - Sample Json Input

```
{
    "payload": {
        "book1": {
            "isbn": "123-456-2221",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "The Ultimate Database Study Guide",
            "category": [
                "Non-Fiction",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellerid1": {
                "name": "sellerid1",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_y",
                        "sellcount": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "sellerid2": {
                "name": "sellerid2",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_b",
                        "sellcount": 15
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "book2": {
            "isbn": "123-456-222",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "C programming guide",
            "category": [
                "Programming",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellerid3": {
                "name": "sellerid3",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_b",
                        "sellcount": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "sellerid4": {
                "name": "sellerid4",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_x",
                        "sellcount": 15
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

######## Sample json case 2 ###############

```
{
    "payload": {
        "book1": {
            "isbn": "123-456-2221",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "The Ultimate Database Study Guide",
            "category": [
                "Non-Fiction",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellers": {
                "sellerid1": {
                    "name": "sellerid1",
                    "cities": [{
                            "name": "city_a",
                            "sellcount": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "city_y",
                            "sellcount": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sellerid2": {
                    "name": "sellerid2",
                    "cities": [{
                            "name": "city_a",
                            "sellcount": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "city_b",
                            "sellcount": 15
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "book2": {
            "isbn": "123-456-222",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "C programming guide",
            "category": [
                "Programming",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellers": {
                "sellerid3": {
                    "name": "sellerid3",
                    "cities": [{
                            "name": "city_a",
                            "sellcount": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "city_b",
                            "sellcount": 200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sellerid4": {
                    "name": "sellerid4",
                    "cities": [{
                            "name": "city_a",
                            "sellcount": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "city_x",
                            "sellcount": 15
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "book3": {
            "isbn": "123-456-2221",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "The Ultimate Database Study Guide",
            "category": [
                "Non-Fiction",
                "Technology"
            ]
        },
        "book4": {
            "isbn": "123-456-222",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "C programming guide",
            "category": [
                "Programming",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellers": {}
        }
    }
}
```

#### required output is same for case1 and case2.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "book2": {
            "isbn": "123-456-222",
            "author": {
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "editor": {
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "firstname": "Jane"
            },
            "title": "C programming guide",
            "category": [
                "Programming",
                "Technology"
            ],
            "sellerid3": {
                "name": "sellerid3",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_b",
                        "sellcount": 200
                    }
                ]
            },
            "sellerid4": {
                "name": "sellerid4",
                "cities": [{
                        "name": "city_a",
                        "sellcount": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "city_x",
                        "sellcount": 15
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried CEL to filter , CEL [playground](https://playcel.undistro.io/?content=H4sIAAAAAAAAA91W30%2FbMBD%2BV255AaQWaFr2gMQDAjYJMYb4ITQRNF2Sa2rNsSPbKUSo%2F%2FvOaSBpt6kVUiW0l9Y5f%2Fd9dxefLy9Big6Dw%2BAlUpGLggIrqTGNgkOYW9gWa%2F1r0LWwTdhYeVMUDMJhf3TwuR%2BGIYN6LQRLN9Fm0Y%2FNEq1TmNPc%2B1RT14n3x8J0AeeoePUKmHX4KRVuJf9NLtzkvQpOONmAbicEd9KJHB3BKZcsRktw48q0gq%2BlSBeyCBJGZdpU3vehK32pVf%2BLSJzQaimoW0omSkudVW0sjx1KS1KSEengj4TbTDqYBe5EOEG2DqbrueTNqOonLrq%2BSSe6VM7jBvv73f3ZAnoV%2B%2FMq9nCJvX14%2FNsLek04XKMo4UaLssGaDA5WlmS%2BeNOtOzZcp2P%2F34Y9gcLozGCeC5VBtn6LXrVu72zR4RqncfhRWzTeUIuO1ijK6IO26MqarN%2Bi%2Fo9%2FZkEvoOfCkLU8Cnj87u3BPTFhTuA0OJ42J2cXcCWxygyrpJ8ixZBFGwgLqEAoRwZ5pkyJOeJjaymPZQWFfiJDKZCaCqNVTsp5bpaV2hB7pn7Nda93nrjt5ro6z7WCs7fo4AJVVmJGsM36O7s%2BkjqaPtwbweOw0qWpQ2szgglLN6A7HpSeGA0h8JZfW25HGGvDwRelA%2F8N0uM1%2FDj%2BdgFsPr%2F5fun3edw2LFeeGbauS7VVZzFFWeI%2FxDFDoayrlVqBhuisyd%2F7JZoPXj2NQY%2BZAfNCkm0Cs4UwWE9qVbuiqsBfrPNS1Wc2ceAPiH8RzV2umg%2Bo3bGQ%2FFq24x40lof4cdffwXB0tHwH70QqmP0GADP1K4oJAAA%3D). Nested filtering this style did not find option in CEL. Looking if any other way using jq.

Comment: corrected the json.

Answer (score 0):

This keeps all those fields under `.payload` that have at least one path `.[].cities[].name` that is resolvable and evaluates to `"city_x"`. Consequently, other fields are removed.

```bash
.payload |= with_entries(select(IN(.value[].cities?[]?.name; "city_x")))
```

```json
{
  "payload": {
    "book2": {
      "isbn": "123-456-222",
      "author": {
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "firstname": "Jane"
      },
      "editor": {
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "firstname": "Jane"
      },
      "title": "C programming guide",
      "category": [
        "Programming",
        "Technology"
      ],
      "sellerid3": {
        "name": "sellerid3",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "city_a",
            "sellcount": 100
          },
          {
            "name": "city_b",
            "sellcount": 200
          }
        ]
      },
      "sellerid4": {
        "name": "sellerid4",
        "cities": [
          {
            "name": "city_a",
            "sellcount": 10
          },
          {
            "name": "city_x",
            "sellcount": 15
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/W7PuhesneGs)

Comment: Thanks @pmf. this works!!. Added one more case. There is slight variation for case 2. This one gives error for cannot iterate over null for case2

Comment: Your "case 2" introduces another level `sellers`. If you just want to support it, add that layer as alternative: `.value|.,.sellers|.[]?.cities?[]?.name` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3y1hXe7ICf0). If you want to support arbitrarily deep nestings, use the recursive descent: `.value|..|objects.cities?[]?.name` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fQsdRsKiYio). However, both filter correctly but keep that new level (as opposed to "required output is same for case1 and case2"). In that case, first reloacate their contents, e.g. `.[] |= del(.sellers) + .sellers` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pz9rKm4roYf).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here's an approach that will keep only those books that have `cities[].name` somewhere in their descendants that equals `city_x` ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iYzuO200jYP)):

```
.payload[] |= select( [ .. | if (type == "object" and has("cities")) 
                             then (.cities[] | .name == "city_x") 
                             else false 
                             end ] | any )
```

A little more modular approach ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5L1AqapvqRp)):

```
def criteria($city):

    [ .. | if (type == "object" and has("cities")) 
           then (.cities[] | .name == $city) 
           else false 
           end ] | any;
         
.payload[] |= select( criteria("city_x") )
```

### Explanation

The idea is that for each book produced by `.payload[]`, we only want to let it pass through if it satisfies the criteria: `select( criteria("city_x") )`

The criteria function produces all possible descendants (`..`) but we are only interested in objects that have a `cities` property. If such an object is encountered, we unwarp the `.cities` property to iterate over each city and check if it's `name` matches `city_x`. Of course, we are only interested in retaining a book, if there is at least one match.

And so for each descendant, the logic produces `false` if the criteria is not satisfied, and `true` if it is. The final `any` checks that one of these elements is true, which means that the matched book should be included in the final result.

A caveat: if the same book has two cities named "city_x", this would produce two `true` elements in the array for the same input object but this is not a problem because we have the final `any`. If it can be assumed that this wouldn't occur, the logic can be made a little simpler by moving the `any` to the `then` clause ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D4YlQ6EgtAJ)).